# Slashes in plain text email causing send failure

Tags: email, smtp, plaintext

A particular mail server I'm dealing with has rejected the sending of a plain text email with a few forward and backslashes in it. It's possible it's confusing these with something else.

The email is simply a contact form on a website, so it's a blurb of text written by someone.

What's the best method for escaping or doing otherwise to prevent issues like this?

I could just strip out all the slashes, but that seems a little crude.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried escaping the slashes, either as HTML-encoded characters or just as double-slashed:-

```
A slash is you! \\ //
```

Comment: Well, that's annoying.

It's possible also, that the server you're dealing with has a data-sanitization routine that's just decided that slashes are evil and HOW DARE YOU use them.

Comment: Yes, very. I tried changing the email to HTML format, but still no success. Grrr.